# QGIS Server not working on Windows 7

Tags: qgis, qgis-server, windows-7, osgeo4w

I have installed QGIS Server through OSGEO4W. I followed the instructions by Anita Graser, as well as the instructions on [this page](http://hub.qgis.org/projects/quantum-gis/wiki/QGIS_Server_Tutorial) but still keep getting a 500 Internal Server Error. The objective was to install a localhost instance to work with QGIS Server in a workshop environment.

What is peculiar is that in a group of 13 laptops running Win7, 4 loaded fine (with the odd 500 error).

Is there anyone who has managed to overcome this? I copied the dll files into the QGIS Server folder, changed the filename to remove the .exe from the filename qgis_mapserv.fcgi.exe, and then added it back on again. Every change I made, I restarted the apache server, but no change to the end result. Is it perhaps an install issue, which is making this impossible to troubleshoot?

Comment: Have you tried the suggestions here -> http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/137496/qgis-server-2-8-on-windows-server-2012 ?

Answer (score 1):

This is what worked for me on windows 7:

Using the OSGeo4W setup, install the following packages:

1. apache
2. mod_fcgi
3. qgis-server
4. qscintilla

All the other dependencies will be installed automatically.

Run the get capabilities to check if it works
http://localhost/qgis/qgis_mapserv.fcgi.exe?SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.3.0&REQUEST=GetCapabilities

If it works you can go ahead and remove the **.exe** from **qgis_mapserv.fcgi.exe** and edit the **httpd.conf**