# QGIS Server Internal Server Error getcapabilities request

Tags: qgis-server, windows-7, getcapabilities

I followed the links from http://anitagraser.com/2012/04/06/qgis-server-on-windows7-step-by-step/ for installing the QGIS server at my Win 7 64bit system but the `getcapabilities` request doesn't work.

That's why I try to start the `qgis_mapserv.fcgi.exe` directly. It's said that many libraries are not found. I added all libraries from `osgeo/bin` to `/osgeo/apps/qgis/bin`.

Now the `qgis_mapserv.fcgi.exe` starts and give the output:

> QFSFileEngine::open: No file name specified

- The apache error-log doesn't show anything.
- The `getcapabilities` request doesn't work and
- I get the following error-text in the browser:

> Internal Server Error

The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.

> Please contact the server administrator, admin@local.domain and inform
>   them of the time the error occurred, and anything you might have done
>   that may have caused the error.
>
> More information about this error may be available in the server error log.

I read some questions with the same problem here but in my case they doesn't work.

- I added all librarys
- installed the `mod_fcid` separately from osgeo4w

Has somebody any other ideas?

Answer (score 2):

This sounds a lot like the problem I was having. I installed qscintilla and changed the qgis config file suggested here: [QGIS Server 2.8 on Windows Server 2012](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/137496/qgis-server-2-8-on-windows-server-2012)

Now I'm getting something back from GetCapabilities.

Comment: Where is the qgis config file located? I am having the same issue but I do not seem to have a qgis.conf or a httpd_qgis.conf file anywhere in the OSGeo4W directory.