# QGIS Server WMS does not work in ArcGIS Desktop / ArcGIS Online

Tags: qgis, arcgis-desktop, wms, arcgis-online, qgis-server

After some issues with my apache configuration (cp. [QGIS-Server - 500 internal server error](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/206776/qgis-server-500-internal-server-error)) and some playing around with setting up things correctly like projections, service versions,... I succeeded in setting up a QGIS Server WMS wich works great (transparency, querying, ...) ...in QGIS, as can been seen in screeshot below (the yellow parts):

[image]

Unfortunately, in my organisation some people are using gisses different from QGIS. Problem arises e.g., when trying to display the same service in ArcGIS 10.4 (via ArcCatalog, Add WMS Server), set up like this:

[image]

My ArcGIS Project is set up the same as my qgis project (crs=EPS:31468), the service seems to be drawn (note the status line: 'Drawing...') but nothing is shown at all, except the basemap:

[image]

Furthermore I tried to add the WMS to an ArcGIS Online map, with no success at all...

[image]

...and the following error:

[image]

Since I use an internal URL, Firefox is configured to connect to the internet without a proxy. Directly typed into the browser, the GetCapabilities request works:

[image]

Comment: The QGIS docs http://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_ogc/ogc_server_support.html tells us that only WMS version 1.3.0 is supported.  I see you have a GetCapabilities response that starts with `<WMT_MS_Capabilities version="1.1.1">` however I also see that the service name is `WMS`.  For a WMS version 1.1.1 GetCapabilities response response the service name must be `OGC:WMS`, so something's not quite correct.  What happens if you use WMS 1.3.0?

Comment: Yes, but in the QGIS example above `http://10.17.34.32/qgis-ltr/qgis_mapserv.fcgi.exe?VERSION=1.1.1&map=flst_ster.qgs` works best, not `...VERSION=1.3.0...` because of some trouble I got in with the axis orientation. In the ESRI examples, it doesn't matter if I use `1.1.1` or `1.3.0`.

Comment: OK, but your WMS 1.1.1 GetCapabilities response is not valid and having a non-valid response might be causing you problems.

Comment: Focussing on WMS 1.3.0, I found that in QGIS I only get the correct result with the parameter `IgnoreAxisOrientation` set, otherwise x and y will be switched (crs is EPSG:31468). The question is, how to tell ArcGIS desktop to ignore axis orientation? Both adding a custom parameter `IgnoreAxisOrientation=1` and appending this parameter to the url have no affect. x and y are switched anyway, and because in this area is no data, the result is a blank map i think. So in my opinion it might make sense to start a new thread on this issue.

Comment: Simple (but at all not very satifying) solution/workaroud is to use `...&VERSION=1.1.0&...` in ArcGIS Desktop. This doesn't care for axis orientation and the wms is displayed correctly.